# Labview and SQL stored procedure - Procedure or function StoreTemp has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, labview

I have a stored procedure looking like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoreTemp]
    (@Temperature float, 
     @Seconds int, 
     @SessionId int,)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Unit varchar(20);

    SELECT @Unit = RecordingUnit FROM ReadLastUnit;

    INSERT INTO DATASET (Temperature_C, Temperature_F, Seconds, SessionId, [Time])
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN @Unit = 'Celsius' THEN @Temperature ELSE NULL END,
        CASE WHEN @Unit != 'Celsius' THEN @Temperature ELSE NULL END,
        @Seconds, @SessionId, GETDATE();
END
```

In labview I prepare the string with parameters like

```
execute StoreTemp %2.1f, %d, %d
```

which takes 3 parameters which are input through a "Format into string" box.

The following error is thrown:

> Error -2147217900 occurred at Exception occurred in Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Procedure or function StoreTemp has too many arguments specified. in ADODBCommand

The above SQL Server stored procedure should basically get the one measurement value `@Temperature` from LabView, and depending on the recording settings (- which is read as @Unit from ReadLastUnit View) either store the temperature in one unit and fill the other unit column with null, and vice versa. Somehow it seems to be getting more parameters, although 3 inputs are specified and 3 parameters are passed through LabView. What does this error mean then?

Comment: You 've an extra comma `@SessionId int,` or it's a typo? and `SELECT @Unit = RecordingUnit from ReadLastUnit;` won't work as you expected unless you've only one row.

Comment: That comma is a typo. And yes, the @ReadLastUnit returns only 1 row, the last entered value for that column

Comment: I don't know anything about lab view but looks like you are passing 4 parameters to a stored proc defined as accepting three. You've got `%2.1f` and then three instances of `%d`

Comment: Also updated that part, it should be one float %2.1f and two numbers (int) %d. So I pass these 3 values to the stored procedure that expects 3 parameters passed, where the float is used to fill in two columns in the insert function. Having a hard time understanding what the issue is. Have tried some manual inserts with SQL queries, and the Stored Procedure seems to work, so it has to be from LabView's side I suppose

Comment: Did you try executing the SQL in SQL so that you know it has been written correctly.  No brackets on your call?  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_stored_procedures.asp

Answer (score 0):

You're only showing the format string for the SQL command, not the actual SQL command generated after running this. You should start by checking that and, as others suggested, running the same SQL command directly.

With no additional info, my only immediate guess would be that your floating point number has a comma as the decimal point, but that's just a guess based on the available information. I would have expected you to be aware of that if that's the case, but you never know.